# Weird error with class integration

Tags: c++

So, I'm just starting to learn C++ and I'm learning how to create classes.
I've created this code, math.h is a header for a class containing a function called AddTwo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int number;
    cout << "Gimme a number: ";
    cin >> number;
    cout << number << " plus 2 is " << AddTwo(number) << endl;
}
```

The compiler generates a few errors about functions in the std namespace like: "cout was not declared in this scope"

Here's the code in math.h

```
#ifndef MATH_H_INCLUDED
#define MATH_H_INCLUDED

int AddTwo(int a)

#endif
```

Help? What's going on exactly?

Comment: Does `math.h` use `cout`?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what's in math.h, we can't help.

Comment: There is no class in your math.h. This is perfectly fine though, it just means that your description and/or understanding is flawed. That said, what if you remove the #include and the call to AddTwo? Oh, and what are the _exact_ error messages you get?

Comment: When posting a question regarding errors, please always include the complete and unedited error log in the question.

Comment: There's no semicolon after your function declaration.

Comment: Do note that there's a standard header that's also called `math.h`. The current code appears to be OK (modulo the missing semicolon), but it's generally advisable to not use standard header names. Because it just might backfire.

Comment: @SaucyGuy Don't name your header files the same as standard header files.  `math.h` is a standard header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a `;` after `int AddTwo(int a)` you usually get a bunch of weird errors.

Comment: The embarrassment! :p Thanks a lot though, it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#ifndef MATH_H_INCLUDED
#define MATH_H_INCLUDED
// If you define the function in a separate cpp file,
// then you just forgot the semicolon
// else define it here:

int AddTwo(int a)
{
    return a + a;
}

//
#endif
```